# How to parametrize allure result directories in jenkins pipeline script?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, allure, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to pass a groovy list variable to allure plugin in Jenkins pipeline script. I need to make the list of results in allure to be dynamic. So, I have come up with solution:

1. Get list of paths to directories on master node where the allure results are stored
2. Create a list [[path: "path/to/directory"], ...]
3. Pass this list via variable to allure plugin

Example of code:

```
def collectResultDirectories(){
  def directories = sh(
    script: "ls ${ALLURE_DIR}",
    returnStdout: true
  ).split('\t?\n')
  def results = []
  for (dir in directories) {
      results = results + [path: "${ALLURE_DIR}/${dir}"]
  }
  return results
}

def createAllureReport() {
  def results = collectResultDirectories() 
  // == [[path: "results_dir1"], [path: "results_dir2"]]
  allure([
    includeProperties: false,
    jdk: '',
    properties: [],
    reportBuildPolicy: 'ALWAYS',
    // Here I am trying to pass a list variable
    results: results
  ])
}
```

1) **results: results**

*Expected:* concatenated report is created.
*Actual:* Empty report with output:

/var/lib/jenkins/tools/ru.yandex.qatools.allure.jenkins.tools.AllureCommandlineInstallation/allure/bin/allure generate -c -o /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/jobName/workspace/allure-report

22:52:11 allure-results does not exist

2) **results: "${results}"**

Exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException is thrown

Answer (score 0):

one correction that should be done for sure is following:
change the line

```
results = results + [path: "${ALLURE_DIR}/${dir}"]
```

to following

```
results += [path: " ${ALLURE_DIR}/${dir}"]
```

note the space after "

apart from it, everything looks ok, please try and come back with more detailed error if there is any

Answer (score 0):

Managed to find a mistake. I have passed an absolute path to directories which is incorrect - Allure is looking for them in a current working directory. Changing a working directory has solved a problem.

Comment: is this still working for you? can you generate the report when passing the 'results' as a dynamic variable ?